# Return number of rows affected by UPDATE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the number of rows affected by an UPDATE query in a Stored Procedure (SQL Server 2005), as a resultset. e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTables
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Table1 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    UPDATE Table2 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    UPDATE Table3 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    UPDATE Table4 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
END
```

Then return:

```
Table1    Table2    Table3    Table4
32        45        0         3
```

Answer (score 170, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTables
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @RowCount1 INTEGER
    DECLARE @RowCount2 INTEGER
    DECLARE @RowCount3 INTEGER
    DECLARE @RowCount4 INTEGER

    UPDATE Table1 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    SELECT @RowCount1 = @@ROWCOUNT
    UPDATE Table2 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    SELECT @RowCount2 = @@ROWCOUNT
    UPDATE Table3 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    SELECT @RowCount3 = @@ROWCOUNT
    UPDATE Table4 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    SELECT @RowCount4 = @@ROWCOUNT

    SELECT @RowCount1 AS Table1, @RowCount2 AS Table2, @RowCount3 AS Table3, @RowCount4 AS Table4
END
```

Answer (score 34):

This is exactly what the [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause in SQL Server 2005 onwards is excellent for.

EXAMPLE

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table](
    [LockId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LockId] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO test_table(StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES('2009 JUL 07','2009 JUL 07')
INSERT INTO test_table(StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES('2009 JUL 08','2009 JUL 08')
INSERT INTO test_table(StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES('2009 JUL 09','2009 JUL 09')
INSERT INTO test_table(StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES('2009 JUL 10','2009 JUL 10')
INSERT INTO test_table(StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES('2009 JUL 11','2009 JUL 11')
INSERT INTO test_table(StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES('2009 JUL 12','2009 JUL 12')
INSERT INTO test_table(StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES('2009 JUL 13','2009 JUL 13')

UPDATE test_table
    SET StartTime = '2011 JUL 01'
    OUTPUT INSERTED.* -- INSERTED reflect the value after the UPDATE, INSERT, or MERGE statement is completed 
WHERE
    StartTime > '2009 JUL 09'
```

Results in the following being returned

```
    LockId StartTime                EndTime
-------------------------------------------------------
4      2011-07-01 00:00:00.000  2009-07-10 00:00:00.000
5      2011-07-01 00:00:00.000  2009-07-11 00:00:00.000
6      2011-07-01 00:00:00.000  2009-07-12 00:00:00.000
7      2011-07-01 00:00:00.000  2009-07-13 00:00:00.000
```

In your particular case, since you cannot use aggregate functions with `OUTPUT`, you need to capture the output of `INSERTED.*` in a table variable or temporary table and count the records. For example,

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
  [LockId] [int],
  [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
  [EndTime] [datetime] NULL 
)

UPDATE test_table
    SET StartTime = '2011 JUL 01'
    OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @temp
WHERE
    StartTime > '2009 JUL 09'


-- now get the count of affected records
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp
```

Comment: OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @temp
exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Is there a reason to favour this over @@ROWCOUNT ?

Comment: @bbsimonbb OUTPUT clause is useful when you need more than the affected number of rows, it allows checking and acting on values resulted from identities, defaults and triggers.

Answer (score 30):

You might need to collect the stats as you go, but `@@ROWCOUNT` captures this:

```
declare @Fish table (
Name varchar(32)
)

insert into @Fish values ('Cod')
insert into @Fish values ('Salmon')
insert into @Fish values ('Butterfish')
update @Fish set Name = 'LurpackFish' where Name = 'Butterfish'
select @@ROWCOUNT  --gives 1

update @Fish set Name = 'Dinner'
select @@ROWCOUNT -- gives 3
```