# Deleting a row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I delete a row in an sql table without previously knowing if it exist in that table or no

```
 delete from table id=4
```

for example I want to delete an id equal to 4 but I don't know if the id having the number 4 exist or no in this table should I use a procedure to check if it exist or can I just use a simple delete statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a simple delete statement to try to delete the record.

If the record exists in the table, it will be deleted.  If it does not exist, then nothing will happen.

```
delete 
from yourTable
where id=4
```

Comment: than no exception would be given ?

Comment: no, exception will be given, see this demo on SQL Fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/227f5/1

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE id=4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it. The syntax is like this:

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE id=4;
```

The number of rows deleted will be stored in `@@ROWCOUNT`. You will not get an exception if no rows are deleted, but `@@ROWCOUNT` will be `0`.

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103260/return-number-of-rows-affected-by-update-statements). The example is an UPDATE statement, but DELETE works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

do like this:
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE id=4;

if there is a row exist which id= 4 than it will delete otherwise nothing will happen