# How to get number of rows updated by a query in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, ado.net, entity-framework-4

In my database, i have a trigger which insert the change log entries when a row in Table tblA is updated.

Now, in my code i have to update it through a plain Sql query like

```
int count = DBContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("<sql query to update records>");
```

This count variable contains the number of rows affected(no of rows updated + no of rows inserted) due to query.

So my question is, How do i can get only the number of updated rows?

Currently i'm using Entity framework 4. I have looked for solution through connected or disconnected model but couldn't help myself.

Comment: duplicated question, found: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103260/return-number-of-rows-affected-by-update-statements)

Comment: @FooBar both are different as this question is to get the number of rows get updated not number of rows affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> int count = DBContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("");

I think you hv to change this to return Select result set

then do this,

```
<sql query to update> 
Select @@RowCount rowcountAffected
```

Or 
suppose your update is

```
update table1 set col1='foo' where id=2
select count(*) rowcountAffected from table1 where id=2
```

The most efficient way to return row affected can be

i) Assuming you only update (don't refresh any record after that)

```
Put Set Nocount ON
Declare @Output parameter inside proc
```

Comment: This query provided the correct result. Thanks Man!

Comment: Just curious to know that is it the only way to get it?