# Getting the rowsAffected output in log analytics

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, rows-affected

I'm trying to get the rows affected output from an sql server stored procedure activity in azure data factory to azure log analytics. I can currently get the rowsCopied and rowsRead from the copy activity. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103260/return-number-of-rows-affected-by-update-statements

Answer (score -1):

Below is the sample code in determining the effected rows from stored procedure in SQL server

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTables
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @RowCount1 INTEGER
    DECLARE @RowCount2 INTEGER
    DECLARE @RowCount3 INTEGER
    DECLARE @RowCount4 INTEGER

    UPDATE Table1 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    SELECT @RowCount1 = @@ROWCOUNT
    UPDATE Table2 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    SELECT @RowCount2 = @@ROWCOUNT
    UPDATE Table3 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    SELECT @RowCount3 = @@ROWCOUNT
    UPDATE Table4 Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
    SELECT @RowCount4 = @@ROWCOUNT

    SELECT @RowCount1 AS Table1, @RowCount2 AS Table2, @RowCount3 AS Table3, @RowCount4 AS Table4
END
```

Go through this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103272/15969833) for complete details